# command SEARCH CHARSET with special character in IMAP

Tags: search, character-encoding, special-characters, imap

How can I find email with subject ã, or á, é, à? Special characters.
I used the command:

```
c: A05 SEARCH CHARSET ISO-8859-1 TEXT {6}
s: +go ahead
c: &#227;
s: * SEARCH
s: A05 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

but I have a email with subject ã in my INBOX